# C - Splitting C-String into words without reallocating memory

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to split a string (const char*) into words and saving the individual words in an array of char-pointer (char**).

My problem is not the splitting part but that I'm not allowed to allocate any memory. I need to use the input string as my memory, but since its a const char* I'm not able to modify it.

My thirst thought was to change all whitespaces into '\0' and save the position of the beginning of the words in the array, which of course is not possible since the input string is const.

The declaration of the function looks like this:

```
int breakIntoWords(const char *line, int maxWords, char** words);
```

The function returns the number of words in **line** and **maxWords** is the size of the word-array.

Everything I found either used arrays as input strings or allocated memory with malloc.

Comment: You could save pair of indices/pointers that represent the words instead.

Comment: Sure you could, @VittorioRomeo, but that does not get you C strings containing the individual words.

Comment: `but that does not get you C strings` There are no `C strings`, there are just arrays of characters, (except for string literals of course).

Comment: `array of char-pointer (char**).`   ==>> `char**` is not an Array, or Array of char pointer. It is only a Pointer-to-Pointer to char.

Comment: There very well are C strings, @Michi.  That the term refers to a particular application of arrays and not to a separate data type in no way reduces its utility for expressing the related concepts clearly and concisely.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Which are exactly those  `C strings` ? I know only `char str[] = "string";`  and `const char *str = "string";`  and none of them are `C strings`

Comment: @Michi, C strings are contiguous sequences of `char`s terminated by `(char) 0`, as you seem already to know since you presented your own definition.  What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: @JohnBollinger No problem here. Could you please point me to the standard reference of this?

Comment: @Michi, In particular, `char str[] = "string"` defines `str` as an array whose initial contents constitute a C string.  `const char *str = "string"` defines `str` as a pointer to a static array of `char` whose contents constitute a C string.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In my opinion `char str[] = "string"` means that you copy the `String Literal` in that Array, but that still doesn't means that there are `C strings`

Comment: @Michi, if your point is that the term is not defined by the standard then you would have saved a lot of trouble by saying so directly.  That *the standard* does not define it does not mean that it is not well defined or that we should not use it.  You knew exactly what I meant by it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Somehow that was my Point. Here is SO and not a learning system and in my opinion people should stick to the standard.

Comment: Have you looked into maybe using `strtok`?  Also what do you mean you're not *allowed* to use memory allocation?

Comment: I'm sorry, @Michi, but I reject your self-appointment to the role of terminology police.  You are welcome to offer well-founded criticism of my speech for being inaccurate, imprecise, or unclear (though correction, extension, or clarification would be better received than criticism in such cases).  You are certainly free to express a differing opinion.  But I do not accept criticism that the words I use, despite being clear, accurate and well-understood, are not the approved words.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am sorry to hear that. I never intended to judge you or your Knowledge. Of course I understand that, but here is SO, and for me this means that, when someone ask what means this:  `char str[] = "string";` a good answer will be: `contiguous sequences of chars terminated by (char) 0`. That's all. Again, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no solution to the problem as posed.  You can obtain a pointer to the start of each word, but in order to use the source string as the storage for separate word strings you must modify it by replacing delimiters with string terminators, as you considered doing.

If the task indeed supposes that you will alter the input line to use it for storage of several separate strings, then it seems that it is inherently incorrect for the function's `line` parameter to be `const`-qualified.  Such qualification is inconsistent with the job the function is supposed to perform.  Moreover, if you are supposed to assign pointers into the string pointed to by `line` into `words`, then the fact that `words` is *not* `const`-qualified also presents a conflict.

The only plausible solution I see to the problem described is to remove the `const` qualifier from your `line` parameter.

Comment: If I'd remove the `const` modifier would'nt I still have the same problem since I'm allowed to call the function with an automatic generated const char* whenever I'm using quotation marks?

Comment: @Treborium, I have interpreted "split[ting] a string [...] into words" and "saving the individual words" as requiring the production of C strings (null-terminated character sequences, Michi) of one word each, as indeed the implementation idea you presented supports.  In that case, as I said, the constraints on the problem make it intractable.  So yes, removing the `const` changes the problem into a different one.  In particular, it changes it into a *solvable* one.  And you are correct, the resulting function would not be safe to use on string literals.